# Angular 7 is not minifying html, js, css files

Tags: angular, minify, uglifier

I have a problem with my project in Angular 7.

The problem is after compilation I have no minified and uglified files in Chrome console. After running project in `production` environment I received this information in console:

```
Time: 31790ms
chunk {main} main.js (main) 11.3 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js (polyfills) 539 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js (runtime) 6.04 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js (scripts) 52.1 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js (styles) 654 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

As you can see `chunk {main}` has above 11.3 MB.

Once entered the Chrome console I can see those files in my Sources:
[image]

Unfortunately, only `scripts.4d10c1b333ada0ab6568.js` is fully minified. Rest of files are untouched and still not minified and uglified.

I have tried to find a solution, and I found that this should be placed in my `angular.json` file:
[image]

This not helps either. Here is my `package.json` file:
[image]

Can anyone help to set my project up to create uglified and minified files?
Thank you!

Updated dependencies from `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "bindings": "^1.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.13.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lscache": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-dropdown-list": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.4.4",
    "ngx-smart-modal": "^7.1.1",
    "ngx-stripe": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "node": "^11.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rollbar": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tiny-slider": "^2.9.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.28"
  }
```

Whole `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-portal": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/project-portal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/app/styles/style.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project-portal:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project-portal:build:production"
            },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "project-portal:build:qa"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project-portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "project-portal-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "project-portal:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "project-portal:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "project-portal"
}
```

Comment: How do you build your app? And how did you create your app? Did you use angular/cli or something else?

Comment: I'm building it and running with command: `npm run start:prod`. App was created with angular/cli.

Comment: `ng build --configuration=production` should cause your build to use the configuration parameters you showed from your angular.json file above. Also, make sure you updated the correct config section in your angular.json file. If you have created more than one application in your workspace there is an entry for each application.

Comment: Could you try to do next: 
Update package.json with ng command:
{
"ng": "ng"
"build": "ng build"
}
and run command 
npm run build -- --prod
and check again

Comment: @Drag13 I have added { "ng": "ng" "build": "ng build" } but this is what I receive after build:
Time: 45504ms
chunk {main} main.a8377ca7b7d82e8383aa.js (main) 10.5 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.20073962a51430aa9622.js (polyfills) 539 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.618bcded6741c4c27fdf.js (runtime) 6.04 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.4d10c1b333ada0ab6568.js (scripts) 52.1 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.21ba0f4957e4e98a179c.css (styles) 619 kB
Looks like still no minification for them, especially for main

Comment: @MichałBrzozowski So you got slightly less build size but it is still incredibly high. What is the size of the whole src folder?

Comment: As I can see my src folder has 3,9 MB :O

Comment: Could you please add your dependencies section to the question?

Comment: @MichałBrzozowski And one more point. Open please main bundle and check if it is minified?

Comment: @MichałBrzozowski probably you have some issues with dependencies. Look here and try to analyze the bundle https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: I have added dependencies to the question. Unfortunately, main bundle is still not minified. As I can see, index.html is not uglified / minified as well... ;/

Comment: @MichałBrzozowski If main bundle is not minified with default command (npm run build -- --prod) than something is very broken. Sorry but I have no idea what is failing so much.

Comment: May you show **angular.json** config file?

Comment: Thank you @Drag13 anyway! I will keep posted if I figure out anything :)

Comment: @Ivanes I have added whole angular.json file to question

Comment: What I have found out is that once I run my project in dev mode with `npm run start` I have minified styles.js file. When I run it in prod or qa mode, I've got whole styles.css file without uglifying or minifying.

Comment: exactly same problem I am facing now. but managed to solve half of it via webpack-bundle-analyzer and source-map-explorer. Not sure why it is not minifying.

Comment: could you please confirm what editor you have used to create the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like I figure this out. "Builder" option in `angular.json` file has been changed. It's because custom webpack which was used in the project. Simply changed:

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"
```

to:

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"
```

that solved the problem with minification all files on production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the `Angular CLI` from your npm `start` and subsequently `build` scripts without using the alias `ng` directly as you have setup, you might want to make sure and get the path correct in the `node_modules` folder. It should be the following (and add your additional scripting; I can't copy from your screenshot):

```
build: "node node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
```

You also shouldn't need that `--aot` flag as that's covered via `"aot": true`. As a separate test, you should run `ng build --prod` independently and inspect the bundles at the output path specified: `"outputPath": "dist/project-portal"` I suspect the npm command you are using for `npm run build` isn't composed correctly and picking up the proper commands/configuration. The reason for the bundles not being minified is flat out because the `buildOptimizer`, `optimization`, or `aot` flags not being read correctly from `angular.json`